# Accessibility of JavaScript on small screen mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, mobile, accessibility

Im working on a mobile optimised site. Im using media queries to detect the screen size and the majority of the content is still shown just formated differently.

The site has some JavaScript reliant interactive tools. What if any are the accessibility concerns for using JavaScript with mobile devices?

On desktop, non JavaScript users see a static list of the same information the interactive tool uses. I was thinking of the same solution for the mobile version but I guess im interested in more general answers for other situations as Ive not ready anything about accessibility and JavaScript specific to mobile.

Thanks

Comment: This seems like an open-ended question. What exactly do you mean by "accessibility"? Most accessibility-related elements of the web are in HTML standards (some in CSS), and nothing in Javascript. It sounds more like you want a list of differences between mobile browsers and desktop browsers, and Javascript is just one portion of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the same rules apply wouldn't they? Some users may have js turned off, you never know.

Mobile or not, it's still on the web and needs to work regardless of js.

Answer (score 0):

Most screen readers work on the DOM.  Properly written Javascript can really help accessibility (just like properly written CSS & HTML).

Not working with Javascript enabled is more of a problem for security conscious folks than it is for most screen reader users.  That being said, a progressive enhancement approach will ensure that your content is available to the widest range of people.

The older WCAG 1.0 Mobile Guidelines - http://www.w3.org/WAI/mobile/

A Newer WCAG 2.0 set of Mobile Guidelines - http://www.funkanu.se/en/About-Funka/News/News-archive-en/Mobile-accessibility-guidelines/